# NodeJS custom session Store, clear expired sessions

Tags: node.js, session, store, arangodb, node.js-connect

I am currently developing a session store for ArangoDB (connect-arango). It works almost identically to MongoDB session store (connect-mongo, hence 'connect-arango'), but the problem is that ArangoDB does not have a built in TTL for its entries.

MongoDB has this and it's not a problem there. But in ArangoDB, I have to do this in the session store somewhere.

Would checking for expired sessions every 60 seconds (using setTimeout) be sufficient, or should I use something else, like checking every time the "get" function is called?

I would use an AQL query to clear them, similar to this:

```
FOR s IN sessions
  FILTER s.expires < DATE_NOW()
  REMOVE s IN sessions
```

If the user were to clear his cookies, the session would never be accessed using the "get" function, which means I can't check if it has expired there.

What I can do however, is to run the above query every time the "get" function is called, but I think that would be quite unnecessary and put more load on the server.

Edit: Just so no one misunderstands, I know how to clear the expired sessions, I just don't know how often to run the clear function (in this case, it's the AQL query above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a skip-list index on expires, running the above query every 60 sec should not create any problems. You can also create a periodic job within ArangoDB that runs this query every minute.

Alan Plum has added a session Foxx app to ArangoDB which basically implements all of the above. I'm not sure if he has already released a documentation. The API documentation is visible as

```
localhost:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/standalone.html#!/sessions
```

If you have any questions about this Foxx application, please fell free to contact Alan at hackers (at) arangodb.org

Comment: How about I use a skip-list, then run the clear query each time someone accesses a session, but only if there has been more than 60 seconds between the accesses. That way, it would not clear every 60 seconds when there's no one visiting the site for say, an hour. I have no problem with having expired sessions in the collection as long as they get cleared at some point.

Comment: This approach should also work, but might delay the request that triggers the GC.

Answer (score 0):

As of ArangoDB 2.3 Foxx comes with a built-in sessions app you can use in your Foxx apps. You can re-use the session app even if you don't want to use Foxx.

You can simply **mount a copy of the sessions app** at a mount point of your choice. This allows you to configure the session TTL as well as other details (e.g. length of the session IDs). The app exposes an HTTP API that lets you create new sessions, update sessions, retrieve existing sessions and delete them. It **automagically enforces the TTL** (i.e. deletes expired sessions) when you try to retrieve or update a session.

Currently the TTL is only enforced whenever a session is accessed. Depending on your use case this may still clutter up the collection with expired sessions. Currently it's not possible to schedule recurring tasks directly inside ArangoDB; there's a job queue but it is not a good fit for this kind of problem. This will likely be solved in a future version of ArangoDB.

I would recommend monitoring over time the amount of expired sessions that pile up in the collection of your mounted copy of the sessions app. It's probably **sufficient to prune the expired sessions once a week** (or even less). As the sessions app will automatically delete expired sessions when they are accessed via its API, the only problem are abandoned sessions (e.g. private browsing mode, or one-time users).

Disclosure: I wrote the new sessions/auth apps introduced in ArangoDB 2.3.

Comment: I do not know much about Foxx apps, but from what I understand, it's something separate from NodeJS. If that is the case, I would rather not use Foxx since I am developing this session store for one of my other projects that is written in NodeJS.

Comment: @Metamist Foxx apps are essentially small web apps mounted directly inside ArangoDB providing custom HTTP endpoints. As I said, you can use the built-in sessions app without writing your own Foxx app. It comes pre-installed with ArangoDB, so you can just mount it (via the db's web interface or from the shell) and don't have to write a single line of Foxx code yourself. There's really no benefit in not using it unless you only want to use ArangoDB as a dumb REST storage.

Comment: There are no built in web apps for me, the Available section under Applications tab is empty. Do I need to download it from github? I am using the latest version of ArangoDB, since I downloaded it from the website just 2-3 days ago

Comment: I'm starting to think my installation is corrupt. When trying to import a Foxx app from the web ui, the ArangoDB server console returns an error: http://pastebin.com/qE2aszXq

Comment: @Metamist could you file issues at https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues for the system apps not being shown and the import error?